# Prevent HTMLPurifier and DOMDocument from converting &nbsp; to Â

Tags: php, html, tinymce, domdocument, htmlpurifier

I am using TinyMCE to generate some HTML.  Note that TinyMCE creates line spaces using `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.

I am then purifying the HTML using HTMLPurifier.  Note that the line spaces are converted to `<p> </p>`.

I then perform some DOM manipulation using PHP's DOMDocument.  I wish to purify the HTML perform DOM manipulation, and will be doing more modifications, but just am showing the portion below to demonstrator the problem.  Note that line spaces are converted to `<p>Â </p>`.

Why is this happening?

Two solutions I found are stripping `Â` after performing the DOM manipulation and replacing `&nbsp` with `@nbsp` before purifying and then replacing back after purifying.  What is the best way to prevent this from happening?

```
//HTML created using TinyMCE and sent to server using jQuery Ajax Post
$message=trim($_POST['message']);
syslog(LOG_INFO,$message);
// Jul 28 09:39:24 devserver httpd: <p>Line 1</p>#012<p>&nbsp;</p>#012<p>Line 2</p>

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Cache.SerializerPath',VS_TEMPORARY_SITE);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$message=$purifier->purify($message);
syslog(LOG_INFO,$message);
//Jul 28 09:39:24 devserver httpd: <p>Line 1</p>#012<p> </p>#012<p>Line 2</p>

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($message);
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$message=$doc->saveHTML($body);    //Select the body tag
$message = str_replace(array('<body>', '</body>'), array('', ''), $message);  //strip the body tags
syslog(LOG_INFO,$message);
//Jul 28 09:39:24 devserver httpd: #012<p>Line 1</p>#012<p>Â </p>#012<p>Line 2</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<p>Â </p>` looks to me like a character set problem. Actually, when I write a `&nbsp;`, convert it to UTF-8 and open it as ISO 8859-1, I get the same result.

Your PHP code thus seems to generate UTF-8, and your browser displays ISO 8859-1. This causes your problem. You need to convince the browser to display UTF-8, or instruct HTMLPurifier to output using the ISO 8859-1 charset.

Comment: Hello Yorn,  While I think you are on to something, I don't think it has anything to do with a browser.  As seen my my example, I wrote all the outputs to a log file using syslog, and even checked the logs on the physical server command prompt.  But maybe PHP's `DOMDocument` is opening it as ISO 8859-1?  How can this be tested?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php, you can instruct `DOMDocument` to use a specific charset.

Comment: Thanks Yorn. Yes, I see that DOMDocument's default is UTF-8, but it could be changed if necessary.  HTMLPurifier's default is also UTF-8, and it seems like I should do everything with UTF-8.  I have also set the meta tag and header as UTF-8, so the browser should be using it (and in fact if I change the browser to ISO 8859-1, things are even worse).  So, it seems like it isn't necessarily being converted.  ???